# file_get_contents works only on localhost not on server

Tags: php, http, curl, file-get-contents, sms-gateway

I have this script to send SMS from Android phone using HTTP invoke:

```
    $number = "+421904xxxxxx";
    $message = "ahoj";
    $invoke_url='http://[fe80::cefd:17ff:fe70:4351]:9090/sendsms';
    $cell_number = $number;
    $messagesms = str_replace(' ','%20',$message);
    $passwordsms = '***********';
    $url = $invoke_url . '?phone=' . $cell_number  . '&text=' . $messagesms . '&password=' . $passwordsms;
    var_dump($url);
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    if (!$response)
    {
        var_dump($response);
    }
    else
    {
        var_dump($response);
    }
```

It works perfectly on localhost, I got message SENT result and recieve message:

```
C:\wamp\www\ridebook\src\setup\testing.php:35:string 'http://[fe80::cefd:17ff:fe70:4351]:9090/sendsms?phone=+421904xxxxxx&text=ahoj&password=***********' (length=92)
C:\wamp\www\ridebook\src\setup\testing.php:43:string '<html>
<body>
Mesage SENT!<br/>
</body>
</html>' (length=47)
```

But on webserver fails:

```
string(92) "http://[fe80::cefd:17ff:fe70:4351]:9090/sendsms?phone=+421904xxxxxx&text=ahoj&password=***********" 
Warning: file_get_contents(http://[fe80::cefd:17ff:fe70:4351]:9090/sendsms?phone=+421904xxxxxx&text=ahoj&password=***********): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in /home/*******/*****/setup/testing.php on line 36
bool(false)
```

Where can be the problem, I read a lot I tried curl, this again works just on localhost. I have other curls which works on server well.

Also there are no restricions "allow_url_fopen" on server is "true".

Url strings are same on both.

If I copy this adress to url bar again works well.

What can be the problem? Maybe beacuse of IPv6 adress, I have no idea.

Comment: What are the lines of code before and after line 36 on testing.php?

Comment: Nothing just code commented out. It can begin from 1st and nothing will change.